# statsmodels GAM: how to efficiently fit multiple models with identical exog but different endog variables

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, fitting, statsmodels

I want to fit multiple (several hundred or thousand) generalized additive models using the statsmodels package. I have different response variables $Y_1,...,Y_n$, each of which i want to model with two explanatory variables $X_1,X_2$ (the same two for each $Y$). $X_1$ is a categorical variable and $X_2$ is smoothed by splines. In the end my models look like this:

$$
Y_1 \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 B(X_2)\\
Y_2 \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 B(X_2)\\
\vdots\\
Y_n \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 B(X_2)\\
$$

**question:**

Is there a way to efficiently fit these multiple models (Where only the response variable changes between models) in parallel or just in a more efficient than doing it in a naive iterative way, while using statsmodels?

Note: i don't want to fit a single model that predicts multiple response variables but fit separate models for each $Y$.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a statistical question. It might be a statistical question - why don't you want to fit one model for all the data and draw power from over the entire data set? If you simply want to fit a thousand models, wrap the model fitting code into some python loop that can be executed in parallel rather than serial.